# After upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10, system is very slow

Tags: 13.10

I got an notification for automatic upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 on two of my systems.. Both systems upgraded ok without any errors.

While the 64-bit system is working great, the 32-bit system is performing very slowly.. the screen is moving very slowly..

a look at the processes show that a process called compiz is taking must of the CPU cycles (as high as 70%) and that is keeping the CPU utilization to 100% all the time.

Please help.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same issue.  Just upgraded, login screen will not display quickly.  Seems entire system is slower to this point as well.  Just trying to figure out what the deal is here.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the issue for me.  I unplugged my webcam and it's now starting and logging in faster than expected.

Can you test this and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Disconnecting didn't resolve my CPU woes, but I agree, it does speed up the login screen significantly

Comment: Try downgrading the kernel as well. I was upgraded to 3.11 and was seeing this issue.  I downgraded to 3.8 series and the issue is now gone.